# Do I need two instances of python-flask?

Tags: python, flask, tweepy

I am building a web-app. One part of the app calls a function that starts a tweepy StreamListener on certain track. That functions process a tweet and then it writes a json object to a file or mongodb.

On the other hand I need a process that is reading the file or mongodb and paginates the tweet if some property is in it. The thing is that I don't know how to do that second part. Do I need different threads?
What solutions could there be?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it with a thread or spinning up a new process that will perform the pagination.

Alternatively you can look into a task queue service (Redis queue, celery, as examples). Your web-app can add a task to this queue and your other program can listen to this queue and perform the pagination tasks as they come in.